# Topology - Composition of two isometric embeddings

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the composition of two isometric embeddings is an isometric embedding and 
that the composition of two isometries is an isometry.

I have been working on this problem for sometime, if anyone could please help me solve this problem as i can not even start it. Thanks

Comment: What was the definition of an isometry?

Comment: Let (X; dX) and (Y ; dY ) be metric spaces. A function f : X ! Y is an
isometric embedding if, for every x1;x2 2 X ,
dY (f (x1); f (x2)) = dX(x1;x2):
If, in addition, f is surjective, f is said to be an isometry

Comment: And if you look at that definition, and at two isometries/isometric embeddings $f \colon X \to Y$, $g \colon Y \to Z$, don't you see how to proceed?

Comment: sorry i see that from the definition, but how would i move further? i cant understand how i progress.

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$
d_Y(f(x_1), f(x_2)) = d_X(x_1, x_2) \quad\forall x_1, x_2\in X
$$
$$
d_Z(g(y_1), g(y_2)) = d_Y(y_1, y_2) \quad\forall y_1, y_2 \in Y
$$
Now take $y_1 = f(x_1), y_2 = f(x_2) \in Y$; apply the second equation, and then the first. What happens?

Comment: dZ(g(y1),g(y2)) =dX(x1,x2) ?? sorry am confused??

Answer (score 0):

Here's an intuitive explanation. (I won't *quite* tell you the answer, but pretty close.)

Suppose we have spaces $X,Y$ and $Z$ and isometric embeddings

$$f : X \rightarrow Y, \; g : Y \rightarrow Z.$$

Now pick two points $x,x'$ in $X$. These points are a certain distance apart. Lets call it $\Delta$. If we map them over to $Y$ via $f$, then the resulting points $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ are still $\Delta$ distance apart (why?). If we map *those* points over again (to $Z$ this time, via $g$), then the resulting points $g(f(x))$ and $g(f(x'))$ are *still* $\Delta$ distance apart.

**Conclusion**. If $x$ and $x'$ are separated by distance $\Delta$, then so too are $(g \circ f)(x)$ and $(g \circ f)(x')$.

It should be easy to turn this intuitive explanation into a proof.

Comment: I now think i see how this can be turned into a proof like you have said, thanks for simplifying this problem so much

Comment: @user109441, you're welcome!